# Calculating joint MGF

Tags: integration, statistics, random-variables, self-learning, moment-generating-functions

This is an end-of-chapter question from a Korean textbook, and unfortunately it only has solutions to the even-numbered q's, so I'm seeking for some hints or tips to work out this particular joint moment generating function question. or I better state that I cannot find a way to solve this particular double integral)

The question (roughly translated) states that

Given the joint pdf of random variables X and Y,

$$
    f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)}e^{-x}e^{\frac{-(y-x)^2}{2}},   x \ge  0,  -\infty \le y \le \infty
$$

Find the joint mgf M(s,t), and for what values of s and t does the mgf exist?

The following is how I approached this problem.

$
M(s,t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{0}^\infty e^{sx+ty}\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)}e^{-x}e^{\frac{{-(y-x)}^2}{2}}dxdy
$

$
=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{sx+ty}\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)}e^{-x}e^{\frac{{-(y-x)}^2}{2}}dydx
$

$
          =\int_{0}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} e^{\frac{2(s-1)x-x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{ty-y^2}{2}}e^{xy} dydx
$
$
          =\int_{0}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} e^{\frac{-(x-(s-1))^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-(y-t)^2}{2}}e^{xy}e^{\frac{(s-1)^2+t^2}{2}} dydx
$

I see $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ in the intergral and y is to be integrated from $\infty $ to $-\infty$, so I believe that I need to make the expression in the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)}*e^-{\frac{(y-something)^2}{2}}*f(x)$  (pdf of a Normal distribution, and integral will be evaluated to 1 whatever the value something is)
and then integrating the expression w.r.t x from 0 to $\infty$ from there.

But I cannot find any useful integration technique to evaluate this double integral.
I tried polar coordinate; making substitution $ x = r cos{\theta} $ and $ y = r sin{\theta} $
which will turn the integral to
$
=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} r*exp(r*((s-1)cos{\theta}+tsin{\theta})-\frac{{r^2}(1-\frac{sin{2\theta}}{2})}{4})  drd{\theta}
$

Evaluating this I got $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ which I feel is incorrect as it's neither of a function of x nor y.

So can anyone suggest me with any hints (possible substitution?) as to approach this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint density can be expressed as 
$f(x,y) = e^{-x} N_y(x,1) = f(x) f(y|x)$
where $N_y(\mu,\sigma^2)$  is a normal density on the variable $y$.

That is

$$M(s,t)= \int_{0}^\infty  e^{sx} e^{-x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}} dy \, dx$$

The inner integral is the MGF of a normal $N(x,1)$, [which is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions) $\exp\left({xt+\frac{t^2}{2}}\right)$

So we have

$$M(s,t)= \int_{0}^\infty e^{(s+t-1)x  } e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} dx$$

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thank you @leonbloy for so much help. I saw $N_y(x,1)$ in some sense, but I wan't too confident with my integral skills, dealing with variables as x and y didn't quite separate out well. It was quite awkward when I tried to figure out the second part of the question (which wasn't posted here) that asked me to find marginal pdf of x and that of y. in which $(y-x)^2$ term didn't really bother me at all. I better practice more double integral questions. Thank you very much for the help.